# download source code, but not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I had a problem with part 3 of an orchard tutorial...

so I was attempting to download the source code for part 4 and continue on from there (which can be found about 3/4 of the way down at the end of the tutorial on the page `http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-4`

However when I run part 4 from webmatrix I get the error(see below)

im guessing this is because iv only downloaded the code but i need to put it inside  a seperate project? is this correct? can someone advise me how to do this?

thanks for any replies

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error states that there is no default document configured in IIS. Attempt to access the document using the full URL.

For instance `http://localhost:28266/default.aspx` (or similar)

You can then [adjust IIS to have the correct default document](http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/default-documents) (if desired)

---

Edit: After reviewing the referenced ZIP archive.

This looks like a changed file zip for the application. This isn't a complete ASP.NET MVC application by itself and, as such, isn't viewable stand alone. I don't have the time to parse the exact steps required to make this application work alongside the demos provided, but be sure you're either combining all of the previous files and folders in order or follow the instructions detailed by the author.

As referenced, this is not a complete ASP.NET MVC application and isn't ready to be immediately rendered by IIS.

Comment: I dont have IIS, do I d/l it and set its settings for my server? Also the URL example doesnt work, do i need to build the project in order to access /default.aspx?

Comment: @John You are using IIS as that is an IIS error screen. Possibly, you are using the IIS Express variant. Update your question with a listing of the files in the `PART4` directory.

Comment: Sorry to say but that answer is off. The problem is not that there is no default document defined: Orchard does not need one. I'll detail possible causes in another answer.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I wasn't aware that this is an MVC project. The error is accurate in that there is no default document configured. As such, my error explanation isn't wrong per say. ASP.NET MVC also has a default document (this is handled via ASP.NET routing). After looking at the referenced ZIP file there is no Global.ascx file. As such, there are no default routes defined for the project (in essence there is no default document).

Comment: He said so on the first line: Orchard. The zip file that comes with the article is not an application, indeed, it's a module that needs to be dropped into the Modules folder of an Orchard instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the application can't start for some reason, which causes IIS to attempt to respond to the request with other handlers. Because there is no default document defined (and there shouldn't), it tries to do a directory listing, which is not allowed in your configuration. Do not focus on what IIS is telling you but rather on why your application doesn't run.

Things to check:

- you have built the application
- you are running in full trust
- you are running in integrated mode
- there is no exception in app_data/logs
- you added the module to a working Orchard instance, in its Modules directory

Comment: @BetrandLeRoy I explained the problem in my response to your comment on my answer. The problem is no default routes being defined by the application for the ASP.NET routing engine.

Comment: The routes are being defined by Orchard. The module doesn't need to define routes (in which case the Orchard default routes will be used), and if it does, it should not do so from a global.asax but from an IRouteProvider. Also, did you retaliate against me and give me a -1? WTF?

Comment: Retaliatory down vote? No, I didn't see your answer as valid. You edited it to add the reference to it needing to be in a working Orchard install so I removed the down vote.

He is attempting to run an incomplete application as a complete application and that is the source of his problems.